# Find out how many possible chessboard piece configurations there are where a capture is not possible

Tags: arrays, c, recursion, chess

Given an NxM "chess"board and Q,R,B,K where Q is the number of queens, R the number of rooks, B the number of bishops, and K the number of knights find out how many possible configurations of such pieces there are where a capture isn't possible in the next move. EDIT: The pieces can all capture one another as if every piece was a separate color.

I'm stumped, how do I even approach something like this? I mean recursion of some sort could help, where after assigning a square I run the function again and try to assign a square again but I'm quite unsure of how to do this efficiently. Of course, I could just run the recursion (N*M)^(Q+R+B+K) times and get an answer but this seems inefficient. I would appreciate any sort of help or approach ideas.

Comment: As is, post is quite broad.  Consider coding "after assigning a square I run the function again and try to assign a square again" to get things started.

Comment: In chess a capture is only possible with pieces of different colors. How does this work here?

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot to clarify, the pieces can all capture one another as if every piece was a separate color.

Comment: What is the expected efficiency?

Comment: Not specified, anything better than O((N*M)^(Q+R+B+K)) like I said.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Also that formula does not take into account the work needed to detect an attack, so I would even think it is *worse* than that. You can cut a bit by not redoing the work for mirrored boards; by marking attacked fields on the board, so attack lines don't have to be recalculated as you place more pieces, ...etc, but none of these optimisations reduces the time complexity.

Comment: The person who proposed this probably isn't a chess player as Knights are usually denoted with an N, the K being reserved for the King. I assume there are no kings in this game? I think you need to add pieces in turn in the uncontrolled squares in turn and mark off squares controlled by existing pieces on the board.

Comment: Given that all of the pieces must be on the board, you should start with the queens, followed by the rooks, bishops and knights, in that order.

Comment: For each square on the board, I would use a flag to indicate that it is occupied, and a counter to count the number of pieces that are attacking each square. When adding a piece, only add it to squares that are not occupied and not attacked, and are at a higher numbered square than any other piece of the same type, then set the flag and increment the counters for the newly attacked squares. If a piece cannot be placed, backtrack by removing the piece. When a piece is removed, decrement the counters for the attacked squares and clear the flag.

Comment: @SimonGoater Yes. The scheme I proposed of only adding pieces of each type to a higher numbered square than already placed pieces of the same type should avoid double-counting of positions.

Comment: [This might be obvious, but ...] A simple reduction is that we needn't test reflections in X and Y. This reduces tests by 4x. For example, a 5x3: If (1) `A----,-----,---B-` is valid, we needn't test: (2) `----A, -----, -B---`, (3) `---B-,-----,A----`, and (4) `-B---,-----,----A`